# .SVC file in VS2005

Tags: wcf

How do I add a WCF Service in VS2005?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need this: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=5D61409E-1FA3-48CF-8023-E8F38E709BA6&displaylang=en

Also, read this: http://www.danrigsby.com/blog/index.php/2008/08/18/what-happened-to-the-wcf-extensions-for-visual-studio-2005/

Comment: Your first link is to Windows _Workflow_ Foundation extensions for VS2005. What do they have to do with WCF? Your second link is spot on, however, and is the best answer one can give to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Can you be a bit more detailed? If you have .Net 3.5 installed, you should have a project template which manages this for you!?

Comment: No, installing .NET 3.5 will not add any project templates to VS, and definitely not to VS2005.

Answer (score 0):

You should really upgrade to VS2008 SP1 and .NET 3.5 SP1. All of the examples you will find will assume these releases. Support of WCF in VS2005 was only a CTP (or maybe beta).